# firebase functions:shell can't find custom functions configuration variables

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to test my cloud functions locally. I have a custom functions configuration variable, so I used the command `firebase functions:config:get > .runtimeconfig.json` to generate a `runtimeconfig.json` file:

```
{
  "stripe": {
    "testkey": "someKey"
  }
}
```

Then I use the command `firebase functions:shell` to start the emulator, but it prints the following error in my terminal:

```
+  functions: Emulator started at http://localhost:5001
!  TypeError: Cannot read property 'testkey' of undefined
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Jesper\intergun\functions\lib\index.js:14:52)
    at Module._compile (module.js:653:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:664:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:566:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:506:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:498:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:597:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at C:\Users\Jesper\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v8.16.0\node_modules\firebase-tools\lib\emulator\functionsEmulatorRuntime.js:532:33
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
!  We were unable to load your functions code. (see above)
   - It appears your code is written in Typescript, which must be compiled before emulation.
   - You may be able to run "npm run build" in your functions directory to resolve this.
```

For some reason it cannot find the variable, and it also seems like it thinks the code is written in TypeScript, even though it is pointing to the generated `index.js` file. I tried running `npm run build` but the result is the same.

The top of my `index.ts` looks like this:

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';
import 'firebase-functions';
import * as Stripe from 'stripe';

admin.initializeApp();
const stripe = new Stripe(functions.config().stripe.testkey);
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution here: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/711

To generate `.runtimeconfig.json`, I used the command `firebase functions:config:get > .runtimeconfig.json`. However, this generated a file which seemed to be correct but apparently had invisible characters that shouldn't be there. Instead, I used this command: `firebase functions:config:get | ac .runtimeconfig.json`. This solved the problem.

Comment: i dont understand how this works but it works after I run firebase functions:config:get | ac .runtimeconfig.json.. thank you very much